# Finding dynamic memory leaks using profile option in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am already succeed in finding static leaks using Analyze option , but by clicking on Profile option just getting profile window, i have already connected device. How to find dynamic memory leaks in profile?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/

[Understanding the Instrument for memory leak checking - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329535/understanding-the-instrument-for-memory-leak-checking-iphone)

http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can’t rely on Build\Build and Analyze to catch everything. There’s one other great automated tool to help you check your app for leaks – the Leaks Instrument.

Go to Run\Run with Performance Tool\Leaks

Where you can see all leaks in table.

For more information refer to this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial)

Refer the Leaks and Plumber section of this tutorial specially.